# Route [sites.contact.index] not defined

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-8

No entiendo porque me sale este error siendo de que tengo mi controlador y ruta definida.

RUTA

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\SiteController;


Route::get('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contact'])->name('contact');

Route::post('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contactsStore'])->name('contactsStore');
```

CONTROLADOR

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Service;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Contact;
use App\Models\Recomendation;

class SiteController extends Controller

    public function contactsStore  (Request $request) {

          $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            ]);

            $contacto = Contact::make([
                'name'=> $request->input('name'),
                'last_name' => $request->input('last_name'),
            ]);

            return redirect()->route('sites.contact.index')->with('Exito','Mensaje enviado con exito');


    }

}
```

MAS DETALLES DEL ERROR

Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::route
C:\pw_ci\pw_ci\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php:444

Answer (score 1):

El error es que estas redireccionando a una ruta que no está definida en el método **contactsStore** del controlador **SiteController**, en específico es esta línea.

```
return redirect()->route('sites.contact.index')->with('Exito','Mensaje enviado con exito');
```

En las rutas que mencionas no hay ninguna con el nombre de ***sites.contact.index***.